# How can I use Angular Material density?

Tags: angular, npm, sass, angular-material

Material has created a density component modifier (Links [here](https://material.io/develop/web/supporting/density) and [here](https://material.io/design/layout/applying-density.html#accessibility)).

I've imported material/density and followed the suggested code in my scss file:

```
@use "@material/button";

.my-custom-button {
  // Sets button density scale to `-3`, i.e. button height to `24px`.
  @include button.density(-3);
}
```

but get errors about not finding the stylesheet. I've scored the web and found no solution to this problem.

Comment: The question is that if this feature was also implemented in angular material components. A quick skim through the github issues list shows that it is not yet adressed. https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4597

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu you can use material without angular material you know.

Comment: As for the OP, can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: @MGX he's asking specifically for angular material....

Comment: He just added the tag angular material (which might be an error). The links provided point to material design. Have you opened them ?

Comment: Yes I opened them. angular material is in the tag and in the title. The OP showed us what feature he wants to use with angular material. I looked around and noticed that those features cannot be used (yet) with angular material. I did not contest the fact that there might be other ways of doing it.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu  I'm using angular material. The material links were for reference since I couldn't fully find it done with angular material and was wondering how I could do it in angular.

Comment: @MGX I am utilizing angular material components, specifically a dropdown. I'm not sure how helpful it would be to replicate that generic of code. I can link you to the angular component examples if that is helpful.
https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Angular 15 there is this guide https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#customizing-density
so top of scss file you add use

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;`
```

then add

```
.my-custom-button {
  @include mat.button-density(-2);
}
```

I noticed that I needed to add that class to upper level element not to button itself. It might be some css selector problem. So make css selector strong enough.

Comment: It's the way density works for every Material component (although it's not specified anywhere), sadly Material v15 is a mess and the users are forced to do such workarounds.

Comment: Do you mean that you want density all components as once. If that is case then you can set density to mat.define-dark-theme( as mentioned in documentation here https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#customizing-density . Here is one github issue related to density. https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4597#issuecomment-1413889184

Comment: And also if you are not using theming that way like in documentation you can use this @include mat.all-component-densities(-2)