# In Angular 15, how can I decrease the size of a Form Field?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, material-design, mdc-components

I'm trying to reduce the size of a Form Field and font in Angular 15 as simply as possible. In the middle of an upgrade to 15 from 13 and the existing UI is quite broken.

HTML

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Select me long text end with ellipse</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

CSS

```
mat-form-field {
  width:150px;
}

.mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
  height: 30px;
}
```

When I adjust the size with those selectors in Google Dev Tools, it works - but it didn't in Stackblitz. However, even if the size decreases, the mat-label text is out of the box and not centered. I've messed with the padding and a bunch of other things, but I can't get it to work.

Is there a simple solution to scale it down to a smaller size?

[Image of what's going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CHxs.png)

Comment: There's density...it's a pain to work with, but probably better than forcing the issue with style overrides. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960501/how-can-i-use-angular-material-density

Comment: Please follow following answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75194777/7007625

Answer (score 3):

Although ng-deep is technically deprecated, I use the below code to change the height of the new MDC Angular Material Form Fields.

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper {
  max-height: 20px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-mdc-form-field {
  max-height: 30px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

A short explanation what the classes are used for in this example:

```
.mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper
```

Is used for the text size inside the form field. Leaving this untouched will render the text outside of the resized form field.

```
.mat-mdc-form-field
```

Is used for the actual size of the form field.

```
.mat-mdc-form-field-infix
```

Is used to remove the padding. Not changing this will push the input away from the form field. Don't forget the !important property here.

You will need to play around with all three to get a set of values that works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
<mat-form-field style="font-size: 12px" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Name..." autocomplete="off"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the size of form field tag by applying css on the tag

> mat-form-field {    }