# Angular Material - Changing the density doesn't affect the html element

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I want to make my matInput smaller than the default size. The html looks like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="input-parent" subscriptSizing="dynamic" appearance="outline" style=" margin-right: 10px; font-size: 12px;">
  <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="input" (keydown)="checkForSubmit($event)">
</mat-form-field>
```

In the scss, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284845/9749118)  answer, and added the following scss:

```
.input-parent{
  @include mat.input-density(-2);
}
```

But, it doesn't affect the size of the input at all.
I also tried stuff like

-`mat.all-component-densities` instead of `mat.input-density`

moving it out of the class to the main scss file

putting it inside body instead of .input-parent

setting the parent class to the parent of the `mat-form-field` instead of the direct parent of the `mat-input`

but nothing works.
I also want to add that changing the density of a button worked, but not the density of an input.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can see, so far this feature is very poorly documented. Here is what I have tested: class definition must be in global style file:

```
.input-parent {
  @include mat.form-field-density(-5);
}
```

if you want to set class on component level you gonna have to user `::ng-deep` :

```
::ng-deep .input-parent {
  @include mat.form-field-density(-5);
}
```

Density ranges not returning error (-5 - 0).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Angular 17.1 and the issue was applying the `mat.input-density` mixin to the `mat-form-field` element. I changed the style to include `mat.form-field-density` instead and it worked as expected (no need to add it to the global file or use ::ng-deep)

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
.input-parent {
    @include mat.form-field-density(-2);
}
```